# Seven Segment Digital Data Recognition using Tessseract / Java

Tags: java, tesseract, image-recognition, tess4j, seven-segment-display

I am trying to **recognize seven segment digital** text from image using **tess4J** .

My input is here

[image]

I have made **some normalization** as follows

1 ] Image **cropped** .

[image]

2 ] Converted it **into binary**

[image]

I wish to **remove the jagged edges** of text from image .How can i accomplish that ?

I have tried different traineddata from GitHub. But nothing works as i wish .

How to **create traineddata manually** ? .

I am waiting for your great suggestions & lot of thanks in advance. . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a combination of Sobel filters (to thin the edges) and Gaussian filters (to blur the image).

You didn't specify which API you are using for image manipulation in Java, and as I'm not familiar with *Tess4J* I will show what can be accomplished from Python (you can use your preferred library for image manipulation in Java, the process will be the same):

```
import scipy
import scipy.misc
import scipy.ndimage.filters
import numpy

def save_image(img_data, counter):
    img_fn = "img_{}.jpg".format(counter)
    scipy.misc.imsave(img_fn, img_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This loads the second image of your post
    img_0 = scipy.misc.imread("TqO53.jpg")
    img_0 = scipy.average(img_0, -1) 
    #save_image(img_0, 0)

    # Obtain edges
    img_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.sobel(img_0, 0)
    img_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.sobel(img_0, 1)
    img_1 = numpy.hypot(img_x, img_y)
    #save_image(img_1, 1)

    # Remove edges from original image (i.e. thinning edges)
    img_2 = img_0 - img_1
    img_2[img_2 < 10] = 0 
    save_image(img_2, 2)

    # Blur image if you want to get rid of the sketchy borders
    img_3 = scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter(img_2, sigma=1)
    save_image(img_3, 3)
```

This will generate the following images:

## img_2.jpg

[image: With edges thined]

## img_3.jpg

[image: Blurred]

You can try with both types of images to determine which gives good results with *Tess4J*, it is possible that you don't need to blur the image after thinning the edges, as the numbers can be recognized more easily.

If after that you want, you can try thinning the whole numbers until they are 1 pixel thick. Maybe that works good with *Tess4J*.

Comment: One thing about using Gaussian filtering is that you make small features like the decimal point harder to detect.

Comment: It's true, when writing it I was thinking in how to increase the separation between the point and the 4 before applying the gaussian, but I couldn't think of a good way that didn't involve thresholding. Maybe a more sensible border detection?